# Leaflet js: Changing the default zoom of the leaflet-control-geocoder map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would like to change the default zoom setting of the map, after the user has clicked on one of the search results using [leaflet-control-geocoder](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder).

```
L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map);
```

The default `leaflet` zoom setting is as below.

```
  var center_ = [0, 0];
  var map = L.map('map', {
    center: center_,
    zoom: 16
  });
```

Comment: Sounds like a question for https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder/issues ?